# What is the purpose to design soft limit and hard limit in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

> The lease manager maintains a soft limit (1 minute) and hard limit (1 hour) for the expiration time (these limits are currently non-configurable), and all leases maintained by the lease manager abide by the same soft and hard limits. Before the soft limit expires, the client holding the lease of a file has exclusive write access to the file. If the soft limit expires and the client has not renewed the lease or closed the file (the lease of a file is released when the file is closed), another client can forcibly take over the lease. If the hard limit expires and the client has not renewed the lease, HDFS assumes that the client has quit and will automatically close the file on behalf of the client, thereby recovering the lease.

Why does it need this feature?
Under what condition will other client try to take over the lease?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another client should only try to take over the lease, if the client currently writing the file is unhealthy or dead. Only 1 client can have a file open for write in HDFS at any time.

I am not sure about the history of this feature, but I suspect the 1 minute limit is to protect against a client losing its lease due to a short pause (eg GC pause or something like that).

The 1 hour timeout is there so the namenode closes files where the client has been dead for a long time.

There has been a recent change where the hard timeout has been made configurable and by default reduced to, I think, 20 minutes.